# fmtlib: shortcut for user-defined types with no parsing options?

Tags: c++, fmt

I am using the `{fmt}` C++ library. I have written many `fmt::formatter` specializations for my own types. Most of these take no formatting options, so each class has a boilerplate implementation of `parse(format_parse_context)`:

```
constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx)
{
    auto it = ctx.begin(), end = ctx.end();
    if (it != end && *it != '}')
        throw format_error("invalid format");
    return it;
}
```

I was hoping that `fmt::formatter` has a default implementation of `parse` that takes no options, but it does not. Is there any shortcut for this? Something like a `fmt::optionless_formatter` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `parse` can be much simpler:

```
constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx) { return ctx.begin(); }
```

You can also reuse existing `formatter` specializations via inheritance or composition.

Comment: I agree this will accept empty format specifications , but it will also happily consume any arbitrary text and do nothing. I would prefer to report an error in that case.

Comment: It will give you an error, you don't have to do the check yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/rd6saj

Comment: Excellent. I guess `fmltlib` does some error checking on the return value of `parse()`. Thank you!

Comment: @vitaut does it mean that the returned iterator should point to a '}'? what is the magic here?

Comment: Either `}` or end of string. There is no magic.